# Tomcat Deploy fail in free.hostingjava.it

Tags: hosting, sql-grant, codebase

I am using free.hostingjava.it for my application, but when try to deploy the web app, it gives me an exception:

Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.org.apache.jasper.compiler)

And I'm getting a 404 error, when I test the below url
http://free.hostingjava.it/-.

The web hosting says that I should use some configuration like this,

`catalina startup.sh -security`

```
grant codebase "file:/home/hostingjava.it/" {
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getAttribute";
    permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/hostingjava.it//-",
    "read,write,delete";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission
    "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.tomcat.util.*";
}
```

But I don't know how add this in my application :(

Any idea about it???

Answer (score 0):

Probably, I think we have to put this grant code in catalina.policy file located in their tomcat server. And for accessing their tomcat server configuration , we'll need a Premium account.